# Pile of Bones - What are they? Where come from?

Tags: dragons-crown

I've seen on some forums people saying the bones you find on the middle of the dungeon are/were actual players. But I don't even play with internet on and still find bones (and some very bad geared).

So what are they? Random stuff or people like those souls in Demon Souls?
Looks a lot more like random generated, there are some wizards with no spells at all, so weird.

Also I've read somewhere I don't remember to take care because hacked bones could corrupt my save file. Hacked? Eh? PSVita can't be hacked yet (just the PSP emulator inside) so is there any truth in that?

Answer (score 1):

They are just randomly generated, no matter if you either online or offline. That is because NPC characters you find should be always near level of your character (so you don't find a too powerful/weak allies).

Comment: Not entirely true. You can also find piles of bones allowing the summoning of other players as NPCs. You have to play with them before, though.